# Optimise code for assigning an identifier based on a string comparison function

Tags: python, pandas

Let it be the following dataframe, where we are only interested in the column 'number'. We will only work with the column 'number', the rest can be left out.

```
| others | color | number |
| ------ | ----- | ------ |
|  one   | green |  12A3B |
| other  |  red  |  23*4C |
|  one   |  red  |  12**B |
|  one   | green |  52ATC |
| other  |  blue |  unkno |
| other  |  blue |  231*C |
|  one   |  red  |  2398T |
```

I have implemented the following two functions to solve the problem I want to solve.

The first one, returns True if the strings are the same except for the '*' character.

```
def matching(row, sub_row):
    string = row['number']
    sub_string = sub_row['number']
    flag = True
    i=0
    # In case they coincide in length
    if len(string) == len(sub_string):
        # If a character does not match sequentially, we exit the loop.
        while i < len(string) and flag==True:
            if string[i] != '*' and sub_string[i] != '*':
                if string[i] != sub_string[i]:
                    flag = False
            i+=1
    # If they do not match in length 
    else:
        flag = False
    
    return flag
```

My goal is to get the following dataframe from the original. Making use of the matching function implemented above.

```
| others | color | number | id_number |
| ------ | ----- | ------ | --------- |
|  one   | green |  12A3B |     0     |
| other  |  red  |  23*4C |     1     |
|  one   |  red  |  12**B |     0     |
|  one   | green |  52ATC |     2     |
| other  |  blue |  unkno |   unkno   |
| other  |  blue |  231*C |     1     |
|  one   |  red  |  2398T |     3     |
```

For this purpose, I have implemented the following function, which works correctly.

```
def create_id_number(df):
    df['id_number'] = '-1'
    ident=0
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df.loc[i, 'id_number'] == '-1':
            if df.loc[i, 'number'] == 'unkno':
                df.loc[i, 'id_number'] = 'unkno'
            else:
               df.loc[i, 'id_number'] = ident
               for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
                   if matching(df.loc[i], df.loc[j]) == True:
                       df.loc[j, 'id_number'] = ident
               ident+=1
        
    return df
```

The implemented functions work. However, when I use a larger dataset (> 50000 rows) it takes a long time to execute. I would like to know if there is a way to improve this code by using some function from an already implemented python library or a more optimal way.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: If there is a new row with `12Z9B`, where the row `12**B` should go: 0 or 4?

Comment: @Corralien I would only match id_number 12Z9B with the number 12**B, if 12Z9B is before 12A3B.

Comment: What are the stats? How many distinct values, how common are the `*` characters, how often in a repeating pattern? How many characters in the real `number` field? Also, how much of a speed-up do you need?

Comment: @JiříBaum The actual number of characters in the variable 'number' varies between 7 and 9. Normally the '\*' character does not appear more than 3 times in each 'number'. Numbers with '\*' characters do not represent more than 5 % of the total data. I would like if possible an implementation without loops, because in Python this usually slows down the process in a dataframe.

Comment: 95% of the data having no `*` character sounds like an excellent speed up opportunity...

Comment: One corner case, what should happen if the first instance of a number has a `*`? For example, if we first see `12**B` then `12Z9B` then `12A3B`?

Comment: @JiříBaum This will not normally be the case. Think of numbers as car numbers. It is very difficult for this to happen. However, it would be resolved by adding more conditions to the matching function, e.g. matching in colour or others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels like there's a clever algorithm for matching the strings, but I can't immediately bring it to mind; let's speed up the rest first, though

One thing is that 95% of the cases are a straight match; those can use a `dict` lookup, which will be very fast. We only need to do the approximate matching when there's a `*` in the `number`

```
def matching(string1, string2):
    if len(string1) != len(string2):
        return False
    for ch1, ch2 in zip(string1, string2):
        if '*' != ch1 != ch2 != '*':
            return False
    return True

def create_id_number(df):
    ident=0
    ident_map = {
        'unkno': 'unkno',  # special case, map 'unkno' to 'unkno'
    }
    for i in range(len(df)):
        number = df.loc[i, 'number']
        if number in ident_map:
            # already seen (or the special case) - look it up
            df.loc[i, 'id_number'] = ident_map[number]
        elif '*' not in number:
            # not yet seen, no '*' - assign a new ident
            df.loc[i, 'id_number'] = ident_map[number] = ident
            ident += 1
        else:
            for prev_number, prev_ident in ident_map.values():
               if matching(number, n):
                   df.loc[i, 'id_number'] = i
                   break
            else:
                # Has '*' but doesn't match anything - assign new ident
                # Note: a subsequent non-* number which matches this will
                # be given a different ident
                df.loc[i, 'id_number'] = ident_map[number] = ident
                ident += 1
    return df
```

The main caveat here is that a sequence like `12**B` then `12Z9B` then `12A3B` will be assigned three different `ident`s, not two. To fix that, we'd have to make two passes, like this:

```
def create_id_number(df):
    ident=0
    ident_map = {
        'unkno': 'unkno',  # special case, map 'unkno' to 'unkno'
    }
    # First pass - assign ident to each non-* number
    for i in range(len(df)):
        number = df.loc[i, 'number']
        if '*' not in number not in ident_map:
            # not yet seen, no '*' - assign a new ident
            ident_map[number] = ident
            ident += 1

    # Second pass - fill in the id_number column
    for i in range(len(df)):
        number = df.loc[i, 'number']
        if number in ident_map:
            # literal number - look it up
            df.loc[i, 'id_number'] = ident_map[number]
        else:
            # number with * - search for it
            for prev_number, prev_ident in ident_map.values():
               if matching(number, n):
                   df.loc[i, 'id_number'] = ident_map[number]
= i
                   break
            else:
                # Has '*' but doesn't match anything - assign new ident

                df.loc[i, 'id_number'] = ident_map[number] = ident
                ident += 1
    return df
```

This will assign two idents to a sequence like `12**B` then `12Z9B` then `12A3B`, and one ident to a sequence like `12*9B` then `12Z*B`.

---

One note: in Python, we can do three-way comparisons like 1 < x < 3; I use that twice in this code:

- `'*' != ch1 != ch2 != '*'` to mean `'*' != ch1 and ch1 != ch2 and ch2 != '*'`
- `'*' not in number not in ident_map` to mean `'*' not in number and number not in ident_map`

I'd have to measure to see if that's actually faster or if it just feels like it should be, but is the same speed...

Comment: Thank you very much. For the string match maybe I could get a list of the indexes with '\*' for each 'number'. Then remove those indices for each word and finally do a simple == between strings. I don't know if that would be more efficient?

Comment: The trouble is (a) making that correct, and (b) making it actually faster... it feels like there is some clever approach, but I can't quite pick it. However, hopefully the speed-up with `dict` will be enough to serve the purpose?

Comment: Yes of course. Although I will try various approximations of the matching function to try to improve it further. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Remember to measure current performance and confirm that it's unsatisfactory before attempting to speed it up further 

Comment: One last question: What python function or method do you recommend to measure the execution time of an implemented function? Thanks!

Comment: For local optimisations (single function calls), I think the built-in `timeit` module? Given the amount of caching etc, you'll probably also want to measure the overall time; that's either just using `datetime` directly, for a quick overall measure the script can just always log, or going through proper profiling with `cProfile` then pulling it into something like SnakeViz. That will let you know where your whole program is spending its time. Of course, that can be its own trap: guiding you toward local optimisations rather than wholesale replacement of key data structures.